# Drag or pan events shadowed by child or parent

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to implement a page that have to handle different gestures in widget tree. I have used GestureDetectors, but they shadow each other. I have also tried SingleChildScrollView, ListView and similar methods but drag or pan events always shadowed by another.
Is there a way to pass these events?

Here is a example that never prints "GestureDetector 1":

```
        GestureDetector(
          onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
            print("GestureDetector 1");
          },
          child: GestureDetector(
            onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
              print("GestureDetector 2");
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 400,
              width: 600,
              color: Colors.cyanAccent,
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some more experience and practice, I found that this behaviour is even useful. Just adding a little bit modularity, one can enable/disable some of them, force order and make them all dynamic

```
    void gd1(){
      print("GestureDetector 1");
    }

    void gd2(){
      print("GestureDetector 2");
    }

    void gd3(){
      print("GestureDetector 3");
    }



    GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
        gd1();
      },
      child: GestureDetector(
        onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
          if(someCondition()){  // conditional
            gd1();
          }
          gd2();
        },
        child: GestureDetector(
          onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
            gd1();  // reordered
            gd3();
            gd2();
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            color: Colors.cyanAccent,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

after some time, i found a way. instead of gestures, pointer events are bubbled.

```
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (_){print("Listener 1");},
  child: Listener(
    onPointerDown: (_){print("Listener 2");},
    child: Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.cyanAccent,
    ),
  ),
)
```